# Exclude categorical level in plots

Tags: r, categorical-data, loess

I'm using R and I have this categorical variable that has some 'NA' values. My stats_smooth loess curve doesn't do anything at this NA point, and therefore the plot looks weird.

I'd like to have a graph without the value "NA".

How do I do this?

**Current code:**

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(factor(Make_ends_meet),number_shares)) + geom_jitter(size=2.5) + geom_violin() + stat_smooth(aes(x=Make_ends_meet, y=number_shares, group=1), method="loess")# + facet_grid(. ~ category, margins=TRUE)
```

**Plot**
[The Loess curve goes up, until it reaches the last categorical variable which is also a number. After that, it stops. The plot continues for categorical variable "NA", which I wish to remove so that I have a plot of values 1 - 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K03Ey.jpg)

Comment: What about: `ggplot(dat[!is.na(dat$M_socID),], ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just filtering out those `NA` values before the plot? A dplyr solution could look something like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat %>%
 filter(!is.na(Make_ends_meet)) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = factor(Make_ends_meet), y = number_shares)) + 
 geom_jitter(size=2.5) + 
 geom_violin() + 
 stat_smooth(aes(x=Make_ends_meet, y=number_shares, group=1), method="loess")
```

Comment: works like a charm! Just wondering - I don't really understand dat %>%
 filter(!is.na(Make_ends_meet)) %>% that section. Can you explain a bit how this works?

Comment: @maria118code - sure, the `%>%` operator in this case comes from `dplyr`. It allows you to chain together, or "pipe" commands. For more information on `dplyr::filter` I'd suggest trying `?dplyr::filter` in your R console.